# How to enable the functionality of "linking files & images in my online web editor"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

I made my online web editor by watching a YouTube tutorial. It is working pretty fine & I did a fine job by adding my personal flavor to it, mainly by altering the CSS code. When I tried to link my external CSS file & an image to it than those tags aren't working, I'm not able to add an external file. Yes, those files are in same location/directory.

Does code mirror library can solve it? I tried that but it's not working.
my JavaScript code...

```
// Creating Dragging functionality
const left=document.querySelector(".left"),
    right=document.querySelector(".right"),
    bar=document.querySelector(".bar"),
    editor=document.querySelector(".editor"),
    run=document.querySelector(".btn-run"),
    iframe=document.querySelector(".iframe"),
    darkMode=document.querySelector(".btn-dark"),
    lightMode=document.querySelector(".btn-light");
const drag=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    document.selection ? document.selection.empty() : window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    left.style.width=(e.pageX-bar.offsetWidth/3)+"px";
    editor.resize();
}
bar.addEventListener("mousedown", ()=>{
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
})
bar.addEventListener("mouseup", ()=>{
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag);
})

// Run Btn event listner
run.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    const html=editor.textContent;
    iframe.src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html);
})

// setting dark mode
darkMode.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    editor.style.backgroundColor="#282A35"
    editor.style.color="white"
})
// setting light mode
lightMode.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    editor.style.backgroundColor="white"
    editor.style.color="black"
})
// live code
document.getElementById("live").onclick=function(){
    if (this.checked){
        editor.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
            const html=editor.textContent;
            iframe.src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For local directories:

One solution could be using the full directory path in the src for the image and the href for the CSS to see if you get an established link.

If you're using abbreviated links and testing from a local directory, make sure that you're not putting a / in the wrong place in the abbreviated link in the src or href.

If you're attempting to link the files for your site and they're all in the same directory, make sure that there are no / at all in the front of the path.

IE: linking image.png and style.css in the same directory together as the HTML file would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> and 
<img src="image.png">
```

If they are in a child directory from the HTML it would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="child/style.css"> and 
<img src="child/image.png">
```

Something as simple as this would break the link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/child/style.css"> and 
<img src="/child/image.png">
```

|| OR this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"> and 
<img src="/image.png">
```